# How do I select the 'Browse' button from a file input html element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, file-upload, jquery-selectors

I have a page that is themed with jQuery UI, but I can't find how to select the file upload 'Browse' button to theme it as well.

Is there a way to do this, or is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think thats possible.

The solutions that I know to work around this are some css hacking that puts another button on top of it, or you just hide the fileupload control and build one with a textbox and a button, calling the hidden one functions.

You can check a css solution here:
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to theme that Button. If you wan't a different style you have to implement the upload feature in a java applet or a Flash animation.